# Set cookie with ramaze framework?

Tags: ruby, ramaze

Before

> request.cookies[:user_id] = 1

After:(get cookie)

> request.cookies[:user_id]

return nil

Comment: Can't just use session data? http://ramaze.net/documentation/file.sessions.html

Comment: Yes.But i need to know about cookies in ramaze... Suport or No?